# After updating Intellij I have this annoying "open browser" pop up whenever I hover over code. How do I get rid of it?

Tags: intellij-idea

Here is a picture that shows this annoying pop up:

[image]

Today I updated Intellij to 2020.1, and that's when I first saw this. It's not fixed mind you. It pops up whenever I hover over my code, which greatly distracts me. Even after disabling all plugins it persists. How can I banish this eyesore to the fiery depths of hell where it belongs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open settings. Goto Tools > Web Browsers. Uncheck show popup in editor.